# Как добираться до разных child в firebase? (Swift)

Tags: база-данных, ios, swift, firebase

Как добраться до **Room1** и **Room2** и выгрузить оттуда **name** и **image**? При условии того что в будущем будет и **Room3**, **Room4**, **Room5** и так может быть до 500.
И как добраться до каждого из **Photos** чтобы выгрузить **image1**, **image2**, **image3** и т.д.? Тут так же может быть **image1**, **image2**...**image100** и так далее.
Структура **firebase** такая:

```
{
  "ABC" : {
    "Home1" : {
      "Room1" : {
        "Photos" : {
          "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
    },
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
        "name" : "Room1"
      },
      "Room2" : {
        "Photos" : {
          "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image3" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
        },
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
        "name" : "Room2"
      },
      "Room3" : {
        "Photos" : {
          "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
        },
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
        "name" : "Room3"
      },
      "address" : "Street",
      "name" : "Home1"
    },
    "Home2" : {
      "Room1" : {
        "Photos" : {
          "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
        },
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
        "name" : "Room1"
      },
      "Room2" : {
        "Photos" : {
          "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image3" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image4" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
        },
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
        "name" : "Room2"
      },
      "Room3" : {
        "Photos" : {
          "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
        },
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
        "name" : "Room3"
      },
      "address" : "Quarter",
      "name" : "Home2"
    }
  }
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашего формата JSON, без изменений, код такой.

```
import Foundation
struct Room {
    var id: String
    let name: String
    let images: [String]
    init(id:String, name:String, images:[String]) {
        self.id = id; self.name = name; self.images = images
    }
}
struct Home {
    var id: String
    let address: String
    let name: String
    let rooms: [Room]
    init(id:String, address:String, name:String, rooms:[Room]) {
        self.id = id; self.address = address; self.name = name
        self.rooms = rooms
    }
}
struct HomeListing {
    var agencies: [Agency]
    struct Agency {
        let id: String
        let homes: [Home]
    }
    init (agencies: [Agency] = []) {
        self.agencies = agencies
    }
}
extension Room: Decodable {
    struct RoomKey: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }
        var intValue: Int? {return nil}
        init?(intValue: Int) {return nil}
        static let image = RoomKey(stringValue: "image")!
        static let name = RoomKey(stringValue: "name")!
        static let prefixRoom = RoomKey(stringValue: "Room")!
        static let keyPhotos = RoomKey(stringValue: "Photos")!
    }
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: RoomKey.self)
        self.init(from: container)
    }
    public init(from container:KeyedDecodingContainer<RoomKey>) {
        let image = try! container.decode(String.self, forKey:.image)
        let name = try! container.decode(String.self, forKey:.name)
        var images = [String]()
        images.append(image)
        for key in container.allKeys where key.stringValue == RoomKey.keyPhotos.stringValue {
            let imagesContainer = try! container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: RoomKey.self, forKey: key)
            for imageKey in imagesContainer.allKeys.sorted(by:{return $0.stringValue < $1.stringValue}) where imageKey.stringValue.hasPrefix(RoomKey.image.stringValue) {
                let image = try! imagesContainer.decode(String.self, forKey:imageKey)
                images.append(image)
            }
        }
        self.init(id:"", name:name, images:images)
    }
}
extension HomeListing: Decodable {
    struct AgencyKey: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }
        var intValue: Int? {return nil}
        init?(intValue: Int) {return nil}
    }
    struct HomeKey: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }
        var intValue: Int? {return nil}
        init?(intValue: Int) {return nil}
        static let address = HomeKey(stringValue: "address")!
        static let name = HomeKey(stringValue: "name")!
    }
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var agencies = [Agency]()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AgencyKey.self)
        for key in container.allKeys.sorted(by:{return $0.stringValue < $1.stringValue}) {
            let listingContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: HomeKey.self, forKey: key)
            var homes = [Home]()
            for homeKey in listingContainer.allKeys.sorted(by:{return $0.stringValue < $1.stringValue}) {
                let homeContainer = try! listingContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: HomeKey.self, forKey: homeKey)
                let address = try! homeContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .address)
                let name = try! homeContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
                var rooms = [Room]()
                for roomKey in homeContainer.allKeys.sorted(by:{return $0.stringValue < $1.stringValue}) where roomKey.stringValue.hasPrefix(Room.RoomKey.prefixRoom.stringValue) {
                    let roomContainer = try! homeContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: Room.RoomKey.self, forKey: roomKey)
                    var room = Room(from: roomContainer)
                    room.id = roomKey.stringValue
                    rooms.append(room)
                }
                let home = Home(id: homeKey.stringValue, address: address, name: name, rooms: rooms)
                homes.append(home)
            }
            agencies.append(Agency(id: key.stringValue, homes: homes))
        }
        self.init(agencies: agencies)
    }
}
```

Ещё раз, для ясности, ваш JSON, чтобы было ясно откуда берётся константа json_so_708714_asis для теста ниже...

```
let json_so_708714_asis = """
{
  "ABC" : {
    "Home1" : {
      "Room1" : {
        "Photos" : {
          "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
        },
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
        "name" : "Room1"
      },
      "Room2" : {
        "Photos" : {
          "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image3" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
        },
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
        "name" : "Room2"
      },
      "address" : "Street",
      "name" : "Home1"
    },
    "Home2" : {
      "Room1" : {
        "Photos" : {
          "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
        },
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
        "name" : "Room1"
      },
      "Room2" : {
        "Photos" : {
          "image1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image3" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
          "image4" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
        },
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
        "name" : "Room2"
      },
      "address" : "Quarter",
      "name" : "Home2"
    }
  }
}
"""
```

Тестируем так:

```
func __test_so_708714_asis() {
    print("[TEST]: \(#function)")
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let data = json_so_708714_asis.data(using: .utf8)!

    let homeListing = try! decoder.decode(HomeListing.self, from: data)
    for agency in homeListing.agencies {
        print("Agency \(agency.id) has \(agency.homes.count) homes for sale")
        for home in agency.homes {
            print("\t\(home.id) is selling on \(home.address) with \(home.rooms.count) rooms")
            for room in home.rooms {
                print("\t\t\(room.name) has \(room.images.count) images")
            }
        }
    }
    print("Room's \(homeListing.agencies[0].homes[0].rooms[0].name) 1st image is \(homeListing.agencies[0].homes[0].rooms[0].images[0])")
    print("[/TEST]")
}
```

В результате получаем следующее:

```
[TEST]: __test_so_708714_asis()
Agency ABC has 2 homes for sale
    Home1 is selling on Street with 2 rooms
        Room1 has 3 images
        Room2 has 4 images
    Home2 is selling on Quarter with 2 rooms
        Room1 has 3 images
        Room2 has 5 images
Room's Room1 1st image is https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185
[/TEST]
```

Этот код полностью работает с вашей структурой JSON, как она есть.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает.:) Но все же сразу извинюсь за очень глупый вопрос (наверно), для того чтобы добавлять новые Room и Home при помощи кода выше, мне нужно добавлять Room и Home в сам код, правильно? А я бы хотел делать это с помощью firebase чтобы не затрагивать код. Объясню для чего это, я планирую вывести приложение в AppStore, но если я каждый раз буду добавлять новые Room и Home в код, то мне каждый раз придется выкатывать обновление, что не удобно, поэтому я и задался вопросом подгрузки данных в режиме онлайн через firebase не затрагивая код.

Comment: Вам не нужно затрагивать код, все новые записи Room и Home добавляйте только в firebase. Одно условие, что структура JSON должна оставаться той же самой, как вы её привели: т.е. имена ключей Room1, Room2 ... Room5 и также Home1, Home2 ... Home500, ... Home5001. Если так, то никаких обновлений кода не нужно. Дело в том, что код строит массивы homes[] и rooms[]. 
В качестве примера:

`homeListing.agencies[0].homes[i].rooms[j].name`

здесь, i и j — индексы массивов.

Comment: все же не могу понять, я добавил в firebase новый Room3 в Home2 со всеми вложениями (image, name), но у меня никаких изменений не произошло в приложении. Может можно с вами как-то лично связаться чтобы это обсудить? Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Если вы покажите новый JSON, с Room3 и Home2, на входе в приложение (как вы в самом начале это сделали), то я смогу объяснить. Также, индексы доступа важны. Для Home2 индекс будет 1, для Room3 индекс будет 2 (т.е. -1 от окончания ключа). А вот для картинок иначе, image1 будет иметь такой же индекс, 1. Это из-за того, что у вас есть просто ключ image, он и будет с индексом 0, а затем идут дополнительно image1, image2 и т.д., они сохраняют свои индексы.

Comment: Я обновил новый JSON в вопрос, но может я опять что-то не понимаю... Мне нужно будет сначала добавить это в firebase, далее сделать экспорт файла в JSON из firebase и потом добавить этот файл в приложение? Или этот JSON файл можно поместить на какой-то адрес и на этом адресе вносить изменения (добавлять Room и тд) и прописать в коде так чтобы приложение получало обновленные данные с адреса? Типа вместо этого let data = json_so_708714_asis.data(using: .utf8)!, прописать let data = "адрес для получения данных"?

Comment: Исходя из того, что вы ранее написали, что приложение вы публикуете в AppStore (и поэтому, конечно, все его локальные ресурсы, в том числе и JSON файл, если он там будет, изменить не получится) — то решением будет предложенный вами 2-й метод. JSON файл помещается на некий адрес (прописанный в приложении), вы будете вносить изменения в этот файл, но не в само приложение. И тогда, если вы напишете так: `let data = GetMyJSONDataFromURL(string: "адрес")`, то получите актуальный JSON, а код его парсинга оставите неизменным.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за всю помощь))

Answer (score 1):

Добраться до **Room1** и **Room2** и выгрузить оттуда **name** и **image** в **Swift 4** можно используя новый протокол декодирования (**protocol Decodable**). Для этого, однако, Ваша структура JSON не совсем подходит. Если её можно упростить, и называть ключи одними и теми же именами: **room**, вместо **Room1**, **Room2** и т.д., то декодировщик Swift будет всё делать сам.

```
import Foundation

struct HomeListingDecodable : Decodable {
    let agency: String
    let homes: [Home]
        struct Home : Decodable {
        let name: String
        let address: String
        let rooms: [Room]
        struct Room : Decodable {
            let name: String
            let photos: [String]
        }
    }
}

let json_so_708714_simple = """
[
    {
        "agency": "ABC",
        "homes" : [
            {
                "name"      : "Home1",
                "address"   : "Street",
                "rooms"     : [
                    {
                        "name"  : "Room1",
                        "photos": [
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name"  : "Room2",
                        "photos": [
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name"  :   "Home2",
                "address" : "Quarter",
                "rooms" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "Room1",
                        "photos" : [
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name" : "Room2",
                        "photos" : [
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185",
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
"""
```

Код доступа на Swift 4 будет следующим:

```
func __test_so_708714_simple() {
    print("[TEST]: \(#function)")
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let data = json_so_708714_simple.data(using: .utf8)!

    let homeListings = try! decoder.decode([HomeListingDecodable].self, from:data)
    for homeListing in homeListings {
        print("Agency \(homeListing.agency) has \(homeListing.homes.count) homes for sale")
        for home in homeListing.homes {
            print("\t\(home.name) is selling on \(home.address) with \(home.rooms.count) rooms")
            for room in home.rooms {
                print("\t\t\(room.name) has \(room.photos.count) photos")
            }
        }
    }
    print("Room's \(homeListings[0].homes[0].rooms[0].name) 1st image is \(homeListings[0].homes[0].rooms[0].photos[0])")
    print("[/TEST]")
}

// MARK - MAIN
__test_so_708714_simple()
```

Результат такой:

```
[TEST]: __test_so_708714_simple()
Agency ABC has 2 homes for sale
    Home1 is selling on Street with 2 rooms
        Room1 has 2 photos
        Room2 has 3 photos
    Home2 is selling on Quarter with 2 rooms
        Room1 has 2 photos
        Room2 has 4 photos
Room's Room1 1st image is https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test2-29e4b.appspot.com/o/city3.jpg?alt=media&token=12a87c0c-ade1-43f9-b76b-ecdaa86cf185
[/TEST]
```

Если совсем нельзя изменить структуру JSON, то тогда придётся менять работу декодировщика: писать своё собственное расширение, самому обрабатывать JSON контейнер и интерпретировать ключи с разными именами как одну и ту же структуру — что достаточно нетривиально (но возможно). Лучше всё-таки изменить JSON и пользоваться стандартным API Swift 4.

Comment: Спасибо, не все конечно еще понял, т.к. мало занимаюсь программированием. Но такой вопрос, я планирую добавлять новые home и к ним новые room,  я смогу при помощи вашего кода добавлять их через firebase для автоматической подгрузки в приложение? Или может быть есть смысл например использовать вместо Room1, Room2 автоматические ключи и из них уже доставать все остальное?

Comment: При помощи кода выше вы сможете добавлять неограниченное количество записей home и room, что касается Swift, т.к. они являются именами массивов. Вместо Room1 будет room[0], вместо Room2 будет room[1] и т.д. Единственно, всё зависит от того, насколько гибко вам даёт firebase определять структуру JSON. В моём первом ответе я предположил, что вы сможете подстроить JSON под API Swift 4. Если это невозможно, и допустим, ваш JSON будет как он есть выше, без изменений, то это тоже возможно, но надо будет написать свой собственный декодировщик. Я приведу код во втором ответе ниже, тут больше места нет